# Python 2.7.10 on centos 6.6 but no IDLE

Tags: centos, python

I installed Python 2.7.10 on my Centos 6.6 32 bit laptop but when I type IDLE at the prompt I get this

```
[sinux1@horriblehost ~]$ idle
** IDLE can't import Tkinter.
Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **
```

Python 2. something else was the default originally

I successfully installed 2.7.10 (albeit no IDLE?)

```
[sinux1@horriblehost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 23 2015, 12:59:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What do I do? I would like to be able to use IDLE, although this whole venture was so I could code Python on Eclipse Mars...

Comment: We'll likely need to know how you installed your custom python -- did you get packages from someplace, or did you compile from source?

Comment: I went on to python.org , downloaded for linux, and followed the readme file, at the cli I ran $ ./configure and then $ make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `make` and `make install` after installing all of the recommended stuff to no avail. Started getting this message

> Python build finished, but the necessary bits needed to build these
>   modules were not found: bsddb185        sunaudiodev To find the
>   necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the  module's
>   name.

I was going to give up, try to erase/uninstall all of it, and try again ... but I came across this suggestion

```
python setup.py install
```

I ran it, now IDLE works.... but I'm still getting the notification about `bsddb185` and `sunaudiodev`

Comment: I just went through all of this again with LinuxMint. It seems you have to specifically run (in Mint 17.2) `sudo apt-get install tk tcl tk-dev tcl-dev` then `make install` and I also ran `python setup.py install` because I remember doing that the first time. IDLE works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try install these packages: `tk`, `tk-devel`, `tcl`, `tcl-devel`, then reinstall `python`.

Comment: I installed everything you said to (I had a couple already). When you say to reinstall Python are you saying to run the make command again? Or should I uninstall it and then download and install again? If that is the case how do I uninstall it?